# Why does my country returns null on creating an account?

Tags: apex, unit-test, class, null

I am creating a testdatafactory. creating a country goes well. When creating accounts my country fields are null if i debug CountryList it returns the created country record.

Factory class

```
@isTest
public class TestDataMaker{

    private List<Country__c> createdCountries = new List<Country__c>();
    public List<Country__c> createCountries(Integer num){      
        List<Country__c> results = new List<Country__c>();
        for(Integer i = 0; i <= num; i++){
            Country__c c;
            if(this.createdCountries.size() > i){
                c = this.createdCountries[i];
            }else{
                c = new Country__c(Name  = 'Nederland'+'-'+i , ISO2Code__c  = 'NL' , IBANLength__c  = 18, ISO3Code__c = 'NLD' , CountryNumber__c =151);
                this.createdCountries.add(c);
            }
            results.add(c);
        }
        return results;
    }


    private List<Account> createdAccounts = new List<Account>();
    public List<Account> createAccounts(Integer num){
        List<Country__c> CountryList = createCountries(num); 
        system.debug('call countries '+CountryList);
        List<Account> results = new List<Account>();
        for(Integer i = 0; i <= num; i++){
            Account acc;
            if(this.createdAccounts.size() > i){
                acc = this.createdAccounts[i];
            }else{
                acc = new Account(Name='TestAccount' +'-'+ i , Country__c = CountryList[i].id);
                this.createdAccounts.add(acc);
            }
            results.add(acc);
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

Test

```
@isTest
public class TestDataFactoryTest {

    @isTest static void createCountries(){
     TestDataMaker obj = new TestDataMaker();  
    system.debug('TestDataMaker ' + obj.createCountries(5));
    }

    @isTest static void createAccounts(){
     TestDataMaker obj = new TestDataMaker();  
    system.debug('TestDataMaker ' + obj.createAccounts(5));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, you are not **inserting** the countries that you have constructed in `TestDataMaker.createCountries()` method. You just create the records, add to those list but never perform the DML operation.

Becuase you never inserted the countries, so in your `TestDataMaker.createAccounts()` method, you won't get the Country Id on this line:

`acc = new Account(Name='TestAccount' +'-'+ i , Country__c = CountryList[i].id);`

as there was no **Id** generated for the country records and thus `CountryList[i].id` would return **null**.

To fix this, you would need to make sure that you insert the country records to be able to utilize their id in your other method when you create the account.